# How To display last updated data in JSON string using Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I Have try to display Last Updated Data in JSON String using Flutter

this is first json string

```
[{"name":"John","leads":"2"},{"name":"Manish","leads":"1"},{"name":"Abhijeet","leads":"1"}]
```

this is my second Updated json string

```
[{"name":"John","leads":"2"},{"name":"Manish","leads":"2"},{"name":"Abhijeet","leads":"1"}]
```

So I would to print or display last updated data is **Manish** or any other name it is last updated

I used to futurebuilder as well as snapshot please help me.

This is API Call

```
Future fetchUsers() async {
String url = 'http://example.com/API/dashboardData.php';
var result = await http.get(url);
if (result.statusCode == 200) {
  return json.decode(result.body);
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed');
}
}
```

Comment: There is not much information to look at. Please explain what you are trying to achieve and include the current code.

Comment: @Arjunrajkokkadan, Sir I have try to display last updated data in JSON string using flutter same as last inserted id in mysql

Comment: How are you fetching the data? (don't need to call me sir btw)

Comment: @Arjunrajkokkadan I have fetch data using API call please check the updated question I was display my API call

Comment: `decoded[1]['name']`

Comment: @RichardHeap , where to put  decoded[1]['name']  am new in flutter ,but if in case I will print /disply any other  last updated  name  how to print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for Manish in the list of maps returned by the API.

```
final data = [
  {"name":"John","leads":"2"},
  {"name":"Manish","leads":"2"},
  {"name":"Abhijeet","leads":"1"},
];
  
final manishData = data.firstWhere((map) => map['name'] == 'Manish');
  
print('Name: ${manishData['name']}');
print('Leads: ${manishData['leads']}');
```

Comment: I understud ,but if in case I will print /disply any other last updated name how to print it

Comment: if I understood it well, you want to display it depending on the "leads" value update. the best option in this case, is to use streams and not api calls. your backend will provide a stream of data, your frontend will subscribe to this stream and will be noticed on every data updates.

Comment: @glavingo, Sir I cant understand what u say stream because Im new in flutter

Comment: streams is just another protocol of communication. contrary to api calls, you just set up a channel once between frontend and backend at view initialization for example. then, you are able to react to updates made on the server in real-time. you will find plenty of documentation online, it is not specific to Dart or Flutter.

Comment: @glanvigno, Ok Sir , can you help me how to implement it? if ur permission or u free

Comment: i do not know which technology you are using for your backend but i can recommend to implement it with firebase. you will find plenty of resources on flutter / firebase streams setup.

Comment: @glanvingo,Ok Sir I will try to it using firebase ,I was used backend on php, please can u share ur linkined profile ID